# Supabase user data not loaded on time when app is loaded so I get null

Tags: react-native, authentication, async-await, parameter-passing, supabase

So in my React Native app, I have screen that grabs user data and pass it to sub components.
However, the code gives the below error which seems it is not rendered before the screen OR maybe it is totally die to another reason.

```
Cannot read property 'user_meradata' of null
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import HomeHeader from '../components/homeScreen/homeHeader';
import NextJob from '../components/homeScreen/NJ';
import JobFinder from '../components/homeScreen/JF';
import ButtomSection from '../components/homeScreen/buttonsSection';
import { supabase } from '../lib/supabase'; // adjust the import path to your Supabase client
  

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => { 
        setLoading(true)
        const fetchUser = async () => {
            const { data: { user } } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
            setUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        fetchUser();
        setLoading(false)
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <HomeHeader user={user} />
            <NJ />
            <JF />
            <ButtomSection navigation={navigation} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

And this is HomeHeader.js that supposed to get the `data`.

```
const homeHeader = ({ user }) => {
    
    const handleSignOut = async() => {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut();
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    } 

    return (
        <View style={ styles.container } >
            <Text style={ styles.greetingMessage }>Greeting {user.user_metadata.username}!</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => console.log(user.user_metadata) }>
                <Text>Press</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ handleSignOut }>
                <Ionicons name="menu" size={40} color="black" style={ styles.menuButton } />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

The error mentioned about  but I noticed if I change the line
`Greeting {user.user_metadata.username}!` to `Greeting {user ? user.user_metadata.username : null }!` it works. But why is that?

Comment: Just to update user?.user_metadata.username can resolve it, but is it the right approach? Is the structure wrong that I need to add this workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to only render the text if the username is available.

```js
{user?.user_metadata?.username && <Text style={ styles.greetingMessage }>Greeting {user.user_metadata.username}!</Text>}
```